# Как вывести комментарии в кастомных записях?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, комментарии

Есть тема Hotello, в ней есть записи Rooms (отели). Установил плагин wpDiscuz, хочу вывести в этих отелях комментарии. Плагин хорошо выводится в обычных записях. Но в отелях не хочет.
Что я делал:

Нашёл файл вывода контента отелей

```
/wp-content/themes/hotello/inc/plugins_mods/wp-hotelier/templates/alpen/single-room/content-single-room.php
```

В нём добавлял

```
<?php comments_template(); ?> - ничего не происходит
```

Пробовал подключить сам файл комментов

```
<?php comments_template( '/wp-content/themes/hotello/comments.php' ); ?>
```

Выдает

```
Обсуждение закрыто.
```

Т.е. насколько я понимаю, надо где-то галочку поставить, типа как в записях
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в "настройках экрана" отелей нет галочки "Обсуждение", соответственно не вывести блок, как на скрине выше
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно и вопрос, как разрешить на кастомных записях/отелях выводить комментарии? В "Настройки - Обсуждение" все галочки стоят
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю проблема в том что при регистрации кастомного типа записи не указан параметр 'comments' в аргументе 'supports'

Comment: Darth KYL, спасибо за наводку! Да, всё так и было, нашёл файл, где регистрировался кастомный тип записи и добавил comments, после настроил плагин, добавил новый тип записей туда и галочка появилась, в итоге в обсуждении поставил "Разрешить комментарии" и всё вывелось.

Comment: Можете закрывать вопрос как решенный

Comment: @DarthKYL у тебя почти полноценный ответ. Стоит его причесать и оформить ответом. А ТСу потом отметить решённым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для того чтобы у кастомного типа записи включить поддержку комментариев их нужно подключить при регистрации это типа записей. Для этого вам нужно найти функцию `register_post_type` и в параметре `supports` добавить в массив аргумент `comments`, либо если этого параметра нет при регистрации кастомного поста, то его нужно добавить в массив с этими значениями

```
'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'comments',],
```

подробнее о регистрации кастомного типа записи [register_post_type](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type)